# Trying to add ajax to rails app to refresh comments however js file is not executing in browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to add ajax to my rails app so that when I add a new comment to one of my objects the page does not refresh and jump back to the top of the page however it refreshes and stays in the same place.

In order to test that the js I will write in order to do this is working I console logged some text in a separate file `views/comments/create.js.erb` to make sure that the JS was executed in my browser.

When I go to my browser and inspect then click the Console tab, when I create a comment I expect to saee the text I console logged. Instead I see nothing.

Can someone tell me if I m not linking something correctly? Here is my repo if needs be: https://github.com/Angela-Inniss/hair-do

Thank you so much in advance

comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    # we need to find the hairstyle route would be
    # hairstyle/hairstyle id/comments
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.hairstyle = @hairstyle
    @comment.user = @user

     if @comment.save!
      redirect_to hairstyle_path(@hairstyle)
    else
      render 'hairstyles/show'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

views/comments/create.js.erb file(this is the text I would like to see in my browser under CONSOLE:

```
console.log('hello ajax')
```

UPDATE TO CREATE.JS.ERB FILE, now that I know the javascript is working (from the console.log that I did above) I added the javascript i wanted to the create.js.erb file (See below) but it does not perform the action I want. I would like the users comment to be inserted at the end of the existing comments and for the page to not refresh and go to the top of the screen then i want to comment box to clear. Can you see anything that looks out of place in the below code: 
I have pushed my repo again for ease of understanding: https://github.com/Angela-Inniss/hair-do

```
<% if @comment.persisted? %>
  // 1.create the html for the review
  newComment  = "<p><%= @comment.content %></p>"
  // 2. append the new review to the list
  comments = document.getElementById('beforeend', newComment);
  // 3. Empty out the input box
  inputBox = document.getElementById('new_comment');
  inputBox.value = "";
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `create` action your are redirecting to a new page, hence triggering a reload of the page. In the case of an AJAX call, you want to render your `js.erb` file and not redirecting

```
def create
  @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.hairstyle = @hairstyle
  @comment.user = @user

  if @comment.save!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js # will render your create.js.erb file in case of an ajax call
      format.html do
        redirect_to hairstyle_path(@hairstyle) # will redirect to the correct path in case of a html call
      end
    end
  else
    render 'hairstyles/show'
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Vincent, I see what you mean now. I now see my console logged text when I inspect the console and create a comment. I am now going to add the actual javascript I want in the create.js.erb file and see if it executes. Thank you for your help! I may be back with another question though :)

Comment: Hello again Vincent. I just want to make you aware of an edit I have made to my create.js.erb file. If you have time please could you help me understand why that code is not working? I dont have any errors and the comment is created in the database  (I can see it in my terminal) but the comment does not post to the page...........

Comment: Hi Angela. I don't think `getElementById` can take more than one argument. I'd do `comments = document.getElementById('beforeend')` and then `comments.append(newComment)`

Comment: Hi Vincent I missed your comment. Yes I realised I had written it wrong :(  I wasn't targeting the element. I was mixing the syntax for ``getElementById`` and ``InsertAdjacentId``. I have added a solution below, which works for now :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out the issue.

I was not inserting adjacentHTML after line 5 of my edited create.js.erb file code.

Here is the amended code in my create.js.erb file which now allows a user to 
post a comment and for the comment to be inserted below the rest of the comments on the page and for the comment box to refresh to be blank once the comment has been posted.

```
  var newComment  = "<%= j render 'comments/show',comment: @comment%>";
  // 2. append the new review to the list
  var comments = document.getElementById('comments');
  comments.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newComment)

  // 3. Empty out the input box
 var inputBox = document.getElementById('comment_content');
  inputBox.value = "";
```

thank you